# Check if now is less than 3 hours before

Tags: javascript, datetime

How to check if a timestamp is more than 3 hours old?

I have a timestamp in the following format:

```
15.03.2011 18:42
```

How to write the following function?

```
function isMoreThan3HoursOld(timestamp) {  
// parse the timestamp  
// compare with now (yes, client side time is ok)  
// return true if the timestamp is more than 3 hours old
```

}

(I need to do it quite often, that is on a table with about 500 timestamps (50 rows, 10 columns with timestamps))

Regards

Larsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should explain itself:

```
var nowMinus3h = new Date, 
    dateToTest = new Date('2011/03/15 18:42');
nowMinus3h.setMinutes(nowMinus3h.getMinutes()-180); //=> now minus 180 minutes

// now the difference between the dateToTest and 3 hours ago can be calculated:
var diffMinutes = Math.round( (dateToTest  - nowMinus3h )/1000/60) ;
```

if you need transformation of '15.03.2011 18:42' to valid input for the Date Object use:

```
var dat_ = '15.03.2011 18:42'.split(' '),
    dat = dat_[0].split('.').reverse().join('/')+' '+dat_[1];
```

Comment: `new Date()` but otherwise a great answer! +1

Comment: Hi davin, the date can also be instantiated with `new Date`, really, see http://jsfiddle.net/Xw93A/.

Comment: I know it works, although I thought it wasn't standard. Just checked the ECMAScript 5 specs and it looks valid...

Comment: That's right. See *The production NewExpression : new NewExpression*,  ECMASpec 262 ed 5, par. 11.2.2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the timestamp to milliseconds and calculate the time difference also in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

For checking this difference you don't need days, months and years. Just hours and minutes.

So if you read this as a string or possibly two strings do something like this

```
function check()
{
int minutes1;
int minutes2;
minutes1=hour_loaded*60 + minutes_loaded;
minutes2=hour_now*60 + minutes_now;
if( abs(minutes1-minutes2)> 180 )
return false;
}
```

also make some statement to check if hour is : 22 or 23. because this method wont work if hour_loaded is 22 and hour_now is 1.

Comment: Hm. First you say you don't need days, and then you say the method wont work if the day rolls around.